# Loop in Ruby on Rails running twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops

I'm going crazy. My each-loop in rails always runs twice for each collection item. I have no clue why.

```
    locations = Location.all

    locations.each do |loc|
       # delay to not overload le webservice
       sleep 1.0

       if [... some webservice call - runs fine ... ]

        # score calculation - V0.1
        score = [... some formula to calculate a score ...]

        score_total = score + loc.score_total
        score_count = loc.score_count + 1

        # update the current record which fresh values from the webservice    
        loc.update(:temp1 => temp[0],
            :temp2 => temp[1],
            :temp3 => temp[2],
            :temp4 => temp[3],
            :temp5 => temp[4], 
            :condition1 => condition[0], 
            :condition2 => condition[1], 
            :condition3 => condition[2], 
            :condition4 => condition[3], 
            :condition5 => condition[4], 
            :score_yesterday => loc.score_now, 
            :score_now => score, 
            :score_total => score_total, 
            :score_count => score_count)

     end
    end
```

count jumps in 2-times steps

some variables I want to update within each iteration are always behind

LOG:

```
Started GET "/loc" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-01 13:37:22 +0100
Processing by WhitelabelsController#loc as HTML
  [1m[36mWhitelabelWsd Load (0.6ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "whitelabel_wsds".* FROM "whitelabel_wsds"[0m
  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36mSQL (4.4ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE "whitelabel_wsds" SET "temp1" = $1, "temp2" = $2, "temp3" = $3, "temp4" = $4, "temp5" = $5, "condition1" = $6, "condition2" = $7, "condition3" = $8, "condition4" = $9, "condition5" = $10, "score_now" = $11, "score_total" = $12, "score_count" = $13, "updated_at" = $14 WHERE "whitelabel_wsds"."id" = 2[0m  [["temp1", 17], ["temp2", 15], ["temp3", 13], ["temp4", 14], ["temp5", 13], ["condition1", "Patchy rain nearby"], ["condition2", "Cloudy "], ["condition3", "Sunny"], ["condition4", "Light rain shower"], ["condition5", "Sunny"], ["score_now", 306], ["score_total", 10934], ["score_count", 48], ["updated_at", Sat, 01 Feb 2014 12:37:23 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[35m (264.2ms)[0m  COMMIT
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.8ms)[0m  UPDATE "whitelabel_wsds" SET "temp1" = $1, "temp2" = $2, "temp3" = $3, "temp4" = $4, "temp5" = $5, "condition1" = $6, "condition2" = $7, "condition3" = $8, "condition4" = $9, "condition5" = $10, "score_now" = $11, "score_total" = $12, "score_count" = $13, "updated_at" = $14 WHERE "whitelabel_wsds"."id" = 3  [["temp1", 16], ["temp2", 11], ["temp3", 16], ["temp4", 13], ["temp5", 17], ["condition1", "Cloudy "], ["condition2", "Sunny"], ["condition3", "Cloudy "], ["condition4", "Sunny"], ["condition5", "Partly Cloudy "], ["score_now", 391], ["score_total", 22791], ["score_count", 51], ["updated_at", Sat, 01 Feb 2014 12:37:25 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[36m (1.3ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36mSQL (1.4ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE "whitelabel_wsds" SET "temp1" = $1, "temp2" = $2, "temp3" = $3, "temp4" = $4, "temp5" = $5, "condition1" = $6, "condition2" = $7, "score_now" = $8, "score_total" = $9, "score_count" = $10, "updated_at" = $11 WHERE "whitelabel_wsds"."id" = 1[0m  [["temp1", 21], ["temp2", 22], ["temp3", 21], ["temp4", 22], ["temp5", 23], ["condition1", "Partly Cloudy "], ["condition2", "Partly Cloudy "], ["score_now", 961], ["score_total", 93375], ["score_count", 61], ["updated_at", Sat, 01 Feb 2014 12:37:26 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[35m (0.5ms)[0m  COMMIT
  Rendered whitelabels/loc.html.erb within layouts/whitelabel (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4318ms (Views: 6.6ms | ActiveRecord: 277.8ms)


Started GET "/loc" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-01 13:37:26 +0100
Processing by WhitelabelsController#loc as HTML
  [1m[36mWhitelabelWsd Load (0.7ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "whitelabel_wsds".* FROM "whitelabel_wsds"[0m
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36mSQL (0.7ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE "whitelabel_wsds" SET "score_yesterday" = $1, "score_total" = $2, "score_count" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "whitelabel_wsds"."id" = 2[0m  [["score_yesterday", 306], ["score_total", 11240], ["score_count", 49], ["updated_at", Sat, 01 Feb 2014 12:37:27 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[35m (0.6ms)[0m  COMMIT
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.6ms)[0m  UPDATE "whitelabel_wsds" SET "score_yesterday" = $1, "score_total" = $2, "score_count" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "whitelabel_wsds"."id" = 3  [["score_yesterday", 391], ["score_total", 23182], ["score_count", 52], ["updated_at", Sat, 01 Feb 2014 12:37:29 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[36m (0.5ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36mSQL (0.5ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE "whitelabel_wsds" SET "score_yesterday" = $1, "score_total" = $2, "score_count" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "whitelabel_wsds"."id" = 1[0m  [["score_yesterday", 961], ["score_total", 94336], ["score_count", 62], ["updated_at", Sat, 01 Feb 2014 12:37:30 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[35m (0.5ms)[0m  COMMIT
  Rendered whitelabels/loc.html.erb within layouts/whitelabel (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3598ms (Views: 4.7ms | ActiveRecord: 4.5ms)
```

Comment: From what you show, it looks to me like the update function is also increasing count. Show us that function.

Comment: edited OP. The variables tempX and conditionX are temperatures and conditions from an weather API. score_yesterday is score_now from the last record pre-update. score_now is being calculated in a formula. score_total is score_total pre-update plus new score. score_count is score_count pre-update plus 1. From the post-updated record I can see that the record was updated twice as the count is twice what it should be and score_yesterday is always the same as score_now post-update. sorry for the complex description.

Answer (score 1):

Was going to write comment, but it will be clearer here:

I'd imagine there to be 3 potential causes of your problem:

1. Perhaps `update` is saving the data incorrectly / before & after the webservice call
2. Your webservice may be taking too long
3. Perhaps something else is messing-up?

---

**update_attributes**

Having looked over the [`.update`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update/class) & [`.update_attributes`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes) methods, it looks like you could replace `.update` with `.update_attributes`

Although the difference escapes me, we use `update_attributes` all the time - it does exactly what you need here:

```
 loc.update_attributes(
            :temp1 => temp[0],
            :temp2 => temp[1],
            :temp3 => temp[2],
            :temp4 => temp[3],
            :temp5 => temp[4], 
            :condition1 => condition[0], 
            :condition2 => condition[1], 
            :condition3 => condition[2], 
            :condition4 => condition[3], 
            :condition5 => condition[4], 
            :score_yesterday => loc.score_now, 
            :score_now => score, 
            :score_total => score_total, 
            :score_count => score_count
  )
```

---

**Webservice**

Another issue may be that your webservice call is taking too long

Any external dependencies obviously carry added latency, which you may need to factor into your process

Currently, you don't have any logic to determine whether the call was successful or not. This could explain your app's increasing the count without the other items (it doesn't have access to the new data):

```
locations.each do |loc|

    if [... some webservice call - runs fine ... ]

        # score calculation - V0.1
        score = [... some formula to calculate a score ...]

        score_total = score + loc.score_total

        # update the current record which fresh values from the webservice    
        loc.update_attributes(:temp1 => temp[0],
                :temp2 => temp[1],
                :temp3 => temp[2],
                :temp4 => temp[3],
                :temp5 => temp[4], 
                :condition1 => condition[0], 
                :condition2 => condition[1], 
                :condition3 => condition[2], 
                :condition4 => condition[3], 
                :condition5 => condition[4], 
                :score_yesterday => loc.score_now, 
                :score_now => score, 
                :score_total => score_total
        )

        loc.increment!(:score_count)

    end

end
```

[`.increment!`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/increment!) method ;)

---

**Logs**

Lots of these types of error can be explained with the logs

The logs will detail exactly which calls are being made & when; allowing us to see what's happening

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
I did not mention an important detail though :/
The webservice I am using is limited to 1 call per second. Thus, I am delaying the function to 1 sec which gets us to #2 of your suggested solutions. I have modified my code and added an if clause (see OP) but that did not solve the problem. Also using the increment! menthod. It looks like the update (or update_attributes, both same results) method is called twice every time.

Comment: Can you details the params sent to the update_attributes method using `Rails.logger.info(temp)` `Rails.logger.info(condition)`

Comment: also checked the log. Also as suspected, the 'locations.each do' loop runs exactly two times in a row. It seems like "somewhat" is simply calling it twice.

Comment: Hmmmm - how are you calling the process? Just from an HTTP request?

Comment: added log in OP.
Through this:
xml = open(url)
weather = Crack::XML.parse(xml)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it while implementing two different functions:

```
def check_weather(location_station)

[... webservice call ... ]

end

locations.each do |loc|
        sleep 1.0
        check_weather(loc.location_station)
        loc.update(...)
end
```